# Change form action and hidden input value on select option choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change my form action depending on the select option choice, the below code [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843802/change-form-action-based-on-drop-down-selection) works just fine:

```
function chgAction() {
    var form = document.form;

    console.log('chgAction()');
    console.log(form.ddownOption.selectedIndex);

    switch (form.ddownOption.selectedIndex) {
    case 1:
        form.action = "http://myform/option1";
        break;
    case 2:
        form.action = "http://myform/option2";
        break;
    }
}
```

However I also need to change the value in a hidden field based on the same choice:

```
function chgAction() {
    var form = document.form;

    console.log('chgAction()');
    console.log(form.ddownOption.selectedIndex);

    switch (form.ddownOption.selectedIndex) {
    case 1:
        form.action = "http://myform/option1";
        form.getElementById(option_dates).name = "option1_dates";
        break;
    case 2:
        form.action = "http://myform/option2";
        form.getElementById(option_dates).name = "option2_dates";
        break;
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work, I have no idea how to go about this. I get a Function not found error.

HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="" target="_blank">

<select name="ddownOption" id="ddownOption" onChange="chgAction()">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value='IR'>IR</option>
    <option value='TN'>IR</option>
</select>

<input id="option_dates" type="hidden" name="" value="1" size="2"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: can you post your html structure?

Comment: Added HTML structure

Comment: Are you including the js function before the select that calls it?

Comment: Looks like the code is trying to change `name` of the hidden field instead of `value`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes I am including the js function before the select that calls it

Comment: @Amand no it's not a typo, I want to change the name not the value

Comment: Ah sorry, just seen which function is not a function! Answers below should sort it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with getting the **hidden** element:

1.On `form` we cannot use `getElementById()` need to use `document`.

2.**Id** given was **variable** instead of **string**.

```
 function chgAction() {
        var form = document.form;

        console.log('chgAction()');
        console.log(form.ddownOption.selectedIndex);

        switch (form.ddownOption.selectedIndex) {
        case 1:
            form.action = "http://myform/option1";
            document.getElementById('option_dates').name = "option1_dates";
            break;
        case 2:
            form.action = "http://myform/option2";
            document.getElementById('option_dates').name = "option2_dates";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I amended as you suggested but the #option_dates name is not being changed. I get an error: Empty string passed to getElementById(). var element = document.getElementById( location.hash.substring( 1 ) );

Comment: it seems problem is in `location.hash.substring( 1 )`

Comment: what are you passing in getElementById()

Comment: I resolved this by adding a default value to the #option_dates hidden field name attribute. Thanks Ankit Chaudhary

Comment: If I don't change the default select option which is case 0: I get an error: "Empty string passed to getElementById()." How can I set a default value in the code above??

Comment: I added: window.onload = function() { document.form.action = "http://myform/option1"; } now it works without changing the drop down selection as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change the changing of hidden to the following.

```
document.getElementById('option_dates').name = "option1_dates";
```

and

```
document.getElementById('option_dates').name = "option2_dates";
```

Answer (score 1):

You used form instead of document. It should be 'document.getElementById()'. You also didn't enclose your id value within quotes.

```
function chgAction() {
var form = document.form;

console.log('chgAction()');
console.log(form.ddownOption.selectedIndex);

   switch (form.ddownOption.selectedIndex) {
   case 1:
        form.action = "http://myform/option1";
        document.getElementById("option_dates").name = "option1_dates";
        break;
   case 2:
        form.action = "http://myform/option2";
        document.getElementById("option_dates").name = "option2_dates";
        break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the form action, that should change when ever select value is changed

```
<script>
        // firt check select event fired 
        $("#ddownOption").on("change",function(e){
            currentVal = $(this).val();
            var url = "";
            var optionName = "";
            switch(currentVal){
                case 1:
                    url = "http://myform/option1";
                    optionName = "option1_dates";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    url = "http://myform/option2";
                    optionName = "option2_dates";
                    break;
                default:
                    url = "http://myform/defaultOption";
                    optionName = "defaultoption_dates";
                    break;
            }

            $("#form").attr("href",url);
            $("#option_dates").attr("name",optionName);
        });
    </script>
```

In your code `option_dates` is not a value its a name but without single quotes javascript treat it as a js value 
so  change your code to

`document.getElementById('option_dates').name = "you_value";`

Comment: Yes, my example does work for the form action, I need to also change the hidden input name as well!

Comment: yes i knew that... i only told you an alternate way to do things and the solution to the problem in your code

Comment: @Meenash Jain I tried your code but it does nothing, doesn't give me the correct url nor the correct option_dates