# Ajax upload not executing the PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have found my errors via console log in chrome and remove them but my problem now is that it doesn't call the php script that supposed to process the data.

```
<legend><strong>Select type of machine model</strong></legend>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select id="machine" name="machine" class="field" >
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose..</option>
<option value="machine1.php">Machine 1</option>
<option value="machine2.php">Machine 2</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Select a file to upload</strong></legend>       
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" size="40" multiple="multiple" />
     <br />
      <p></p>
       <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload"/>
       <br />
        <br />
    </form>
    <div id="information">
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Uploaded Files</strong></legend>
    <div id="uploaded"></div>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
jQuery('#upload').click(function(e){


    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    var page = $("#machine option:selected").val();

    //check the output here
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("formData",formData)

    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contenType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#information").empty();
            $("#information").append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

});

It's becoming my dilemma and I have been searching google for 3 straight days now and I found some useful codes but when I apply it to mine, it does not work even errors I have none. Thanks in advance.

I finally got the answer to my question, thanks for the help that you gave me..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form1").submit(function(e){
var formObj = $(this);
var page = $("#machine option:selected").val();

if(window.FormData !== undefined)
{
var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
        $("#uploaded").empty();
        $("#uploaded").append(data);

}
});
e.preventDefault();

}
});

});
```

Comment: What are the errors that you get ?

Comment: None exactly that's why I am getting frustrated...

Comment: I'll try to add it and see if it solves my problem...

Comment: console.log out your click event for the formData etc does this return anything? if using chrome, check the network and see if any requests are being sent etc....

Comment: Do you want to upload file using ajax only?

Comment: does your ajax call works? check in browser console.

Comment: where should I put console.log?

Comment: Yes I want to upload via ajax so that the form will not generate blank page when it is submitted.

Comment: did you even include jquery? lol

Comment: Yes http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery.1.11.0/jquery.min.js, code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js, code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js and http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: I edited my question. Please check if someone can help me with this.

Comment: I also added the malsup upload plugin but nothings happened..

Comment: The last code that I posted was already working but the problem is that it uploads twice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your formdata, this is not a solution but will help you debug your own code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#upload').click(function(e){


        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        var page = $("#machine option:selected").val();

        //check the output here
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("formData",formData)

        $.ajax({
            url: page,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contenType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#information").empty();
                $("#information").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Still not working or maybe I have the wrong jquery library....

Comment: Do I need to include this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples just to make this work?

Comment: I edited my question. Please check if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    function eventListener(){
        $('#upload').click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
            var page = $("#machine option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: page,
                type: 'POST',
                data: { formData : formData },
                cache: false,
                contenType: false,
                processData: false,
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#information").empty();
                $("#information").append(data);
            });
        });
    }
eventListener();
}
```

With that you can access your formData variable on PHP with $_POST["formData"]. But it's hard to help you further without really knowing what you want to achieve. Give us more informations please and tell us what your "data" should return and returns in fact in console.
Hope I could help.

Comment: As you can see from my code that I want to submit via ajax the uploaded files then select which php process to be executed based on the machine type...

Comment: Have you tried my code? I'm not sure but it's possible that your script don't get started. That's maybe the reason why you don't get any result or error. Use the $( document ).ready(function(){ function eventListener(){ "your onclick function here" } } to get it started.

Comment: Sorry for the delay response but I will try it now.

Comment: Sorry but I tried it and the same problem no output no error....

Comment: I edited my question and help me close this question of mine.

Comment: So was it the answere? If no, what does the console output?